# Closest classical (heuristic) optimization problem in literature to the problem I have given

Tags: reference-request, optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization

Thanks in advance for the help.

Throughout optimization and heuristic search literature there are several classical problems including, but not limited to, traveling salesman, 8 queens, knapsack, etc.  Consider the following optimization problem that I have given below.

Let $X$ be a discrete solution (specifically a set of elements) and $f(X)$ an evaluation function that I would like to optimize.  $X$ may have any number of elements as long as $\sum_{x \in X}x = P$ where $P \in N^+$ and $\forall x \in X, x \in N^+$.

I'm interested in using a heuristic to solve this specific problem and would like to read up about how problems of this type have been solved in literature.  This problem seems to be relatively simple and therefore I would assume that it can be classified as a specific case of a much more general, classical and well studied problem such as the traveling salesman problem.  Is this the case, and if so, what would the problem be?  If not, is anyone aware of work that has been done on problems of this type or similar? (It is somewhat similar in someways to the knapsack problem but I'm hoping for something much similar or a classical problem that the problem I have given reduces to).

edit:
I should also add that the order of the elements $x$ within the set $X$ impacts the value of $f(X)$.  There are no constraints, however, on this ordering.  One solution might be 2,1,2,3; another 2,1,3,2; and finally another 4,4

Comment: HXSP1947 : Depending on $f(X)$ it could be Integer Programming, Quadratic Programming $\dots$ If $P$ is small then discrete constraints can be expressed as $(x_k - 1)\dots(x_k-P) = 0$ and Lagrange Multipliers used with  Grobner Basis.

Comment: HXSP1947 : Greedy algorithm followed by k-opt (iteratively swap k elements to improve the cost), Genetic Algorithms $\dots$

Comment: @arthur I'm specifically interested in some kind of heuristic rather than an exact answer ($f(X)$ is just too complicated).  Genetic algorithms is definitely something that I've been thinking about and is at the top of the things that I'm considering.  However, I was hoping for a paper or two that tackle these kinds of problems so that not only can I have a better insight in selecting the algorithm, but also some insight in how to tune it (ie the mutation function to use, etc)

Comment: HXSP1947 :  De Jong's test functions http://www2.denizyuret.com/pub/aitr1569/node19.html were used as a test set for genetic algorithms and other methods. Performance depends on the terrain i.e. $f(X)$ properties.

Comment: HXSP1947 : Global Optimization of MINLP (Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming) by Evolutionary Algorithms http://www.midaco-solver.com/data/pub/MIDACO_APMonitor.pdf

Comment: HXSP1947 : Their publications : http://www.midaco-solver.com/index.php/about/publications The principals thesis : http://www.midaco-solver.com/data/pub/Thesis_Schlueter.pdf

Comment: I'm a little confused. What exactly are you asking for in this problem? What exactly are you trying to optimize? Either way, it looks like you're talking about [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).

Comment: @AlgorithmsX, Close, but not exactly.  I'm actually talking about something called a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).  What I'm interested in is creating an algorithm to search a solution space of compositions to satisfy a solution to a function that I have.  Here a satisfying solution is one that results in my function returning a value greater than some tolerance.  For example, a satisfying solution to the function $f(x) = x$ for $f(x) > 5$ would be 6.  Unfortunately, my function is too computationally expensive to directly calculate.

Comment: I do however have a surrogate function in the form of a simulation.  I know that similar solutions will result in similar evaluations of my function, but I don't know yet what kind function to use as for a local neighborhood search in the case of an algorithm like Variable neighborhood search (as an example).  I'm not so much interested in finding a solution to this problem here (this is after all a research problem that I'm trying to solve), but instead heuristic search methods that have been used to solve similar problems.  Any insight into whether I should closely at a GA, tabu search, VNS

Comment: , etc is what I'm looking for.  I have a decent background with heuristic search algorithms but not so much when determining which algorithms tend to work best with which problems (in this case solving what I've been referring to as a ordered knapsack problem).

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is very similar to a finding a solution to the knapsack problem, you might try using a [backtracking algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). They tend to work "pretty fast" (i.e. still exponential, but much faster than a simple brute force search). Backtracking tends to work well when you need to find an exact answer and there is an easy way to determine whether or not a possible solution tree can be abandoned. Backtracking also has the benefit of finding all the possible solutions.

Greedy algorithms only really work for things like the Travelling Salesman problem, where you are trying to minimize or maximize a value, and even then they are only good starting points, as they do not actually find the best solution. A greedy algorithm with a backtracking algorithm would set you up pretty well.

Tabu searches appear to work well when you are trying to get within a range of values, like the knapsack problem adjusted so that instead of adding up to an exact number, you have to add up to any number within a range. Tabu searches also have the problems of not necessarily finding all possible solutions and occasionally getting stuck inside a loop.

I don't know a lot about VNS, but it seems to be generally applicable to a lot of situations.

From what I can gather, I would suggest either using backtracking or VNS.

Answer (score 0):

If the properties of the function $f(X)$ is unknown (ie, any relations between its value is unknown), the only way - complete listing of all possible combinations of elements.

If the function increases with any new element adding then some optimization methods became available. In particular, if function increases, moreover for large items - to a greater extent, it becomes possible "greedy" brute force methods, with which to carry on sorting in descending order. That case can be considered as variant of [knapsnack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).